# Properties of a matrix $G$ where $GA=BG$ if $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

What are the properties of an $n\times n$ matrix $G$ if:

$GA=BG \space\space\space  \space\space\space  \space\space\space A,B\in O(n) $

I suspect that $G$'s columns must be mutually orthogonal, but cannot proved so.

Edit: For particular matrices $A,B$, which are fixed with respect to $G$.

Comment: Counter example: take $A=B=I$ . Then the relation holds for every $G$.

Comment: If you keep $A$ unchanged and vary $B$, I think you can quickly prove $G$ must be zero.  Is the modified question really what you wanted to ask?

Comment: I think your claim is true in the case where $A,B$ are fixed and $G$ is invertible, since I interpret this as saying $A$ and $B$ are geometrically the same map, but one is expressed in the basis obtained by applying $G$ to the other. So $G$ has orthogonal columns, but not necessarily unit determinant.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger Thank you. Could you elaborate? What do you mean by "geometrically the same map"?

Comment: If $G$ is invertible, this tells you that $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices. This doesn't say much about $G$, but it says quite a bit about $A$ and $B$. For example, they have the same deteminant. Also, the Sylvester Equation might be useful here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation
Maybe this could give you criteria on when $G$ is uniquely determined.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $A=B=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$-identity matrix, we see that we need to impose some condition on $(A,B)$ to have interesting results.

Please let me know if you meant: "For all orthogonal matrices $A$, $B$." Edit: In that case take $A=I_n$, $B=-I_n$ and infer $G=0$ (real entries).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: When I choose "comment" above, I get the error message "You must have 50 reputation to comment". Also: Are there guidelines for deciding what should be a comment and what should be an answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette

Comment: Thanks @ShawSa, that is helpful. I don't understand however why I need more reputation points to comment.

Comment: @oloid Having a small barrier to entry keeps the quality of the comments high I think. This would have been a good comment, but you've already earned more that 50 rep within a few days so I don't think that's a good argument against the policy. Welcome to SE!